# remove string ends with certain extension in a file

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed

Need to remove .sql entry in file

I have file which contains strings ends with both .class and .sql and I need to remove only string which ends with .sql in the file

**file.txt**

```
actual.class
actual1.class
actual2.class
actual3.class
actual4.class
test.sql
test2.sql
test3.sql
test4.sql
test5.sql
```

Output file which i expect is

```
actual.class
actual1.class
actual2.class
actual3.class
actual4.class
```

Using below script but not able to achieve

```
for i in `cat file.txt` ; do
    fname=`echo ${i} | cut -d "." -f1`
    echo ${fname}
    if file=${fname}.sql
    then
    sed "/${fname}.sql/d" file.txt > output_file.txt
    else
    exit 0
    fi
done
```

with above script getting below output

```
actual.class
actual1.class
actual2.class
actual3.class
actual4.class
test.sql
test2.sql
test3.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

**`grep`** solution:

```
grep -q '.\.sql$' file.txt && grep -v '\.sql$' file.txt > output_file.txt
```

The 2nd `grep` statement/command will be executed only if the 1st one returned zero exit status `0` if any match against pattern `.\.sql$` is found

---

The final `output_file.txt` content:

```
actual.class
actual1.class
actual2.class
actual3.class
actual4.class
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using `sed`

  ```
  sed '/\.sql$/d' test.txt
  ```
- For bash (3.2+)

  ```
  while read -r line; do [[ ! $line =~ .sql ]] && echo "$line"; done <test.txt
  ```
- Using perl

  ```
  perl -ni.bak -e "print unless /.sql/" test.txt
  ```

Comment: Anchoring the pattern to $ end-of-line would be an improvement

Answer (score 0):

I think there are already good solutions before this post. However I would like to point out several issues with the script originally posted.

- `for i in $(cat ...)` is not good as it seperates your input by spaces by default as well, not just by newline.
- The if statement doesn't make sense as `file` is not defined. For a typical `if` statement you would need to invoke `test`, usually by putting things inside a pair of square brackets. For example, `if [ $f = "abc" ]; then`. Note that all spaces here are necessary.
- `exit 0` stops the script from handling all the lines after the given line, I believe that is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

Another grep, just invert the match

```
grep -v "\.sql$" filelist
```